# Solve the logarithmic equation: $\log_2(x^2 − 5x − 28) = 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I distributed the the log 
$$\log_2 x^2 - \log_2 2x - \log_2 27 = 3$$
but I am stuck at that point. Any hints?

Comment: you cannot distribute $\log$. Please note $\log(A+B) \neq \log A+\log B$.

Comment: As often happens, many of the posted answers are more complicated than they need to be.  I hope my posted answer is as simple as the answer really is.  At any rate, you cannot distributed logarithms like that.  I've up-voted the question and some of the answers.  Why hasn't anyone else up-voted the question?

Answer (score 8):

Just use definition. $\log_b A=c$ means $b^c=A$. Thus your question becomes.
$$x^2-5x-28=2^3$$
Now solve for $x$.

Comment: This is really the critical point to understand. Somehow it seems teachers don't always impress upon students that a logarithm is just the exponent required to turn the base ($b$) into the given value ($A$). If the student doesn't understand this, there is no hope of understanding how to work with logarithms. +1.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing is that you can't distribute the $\log$, since it isn't a number, it's a function that doesn't obey linearity, i.e. $\log(\alpha+\beta)\neq\log\alpha+\log\beta$.

You can solve this problem this way: (move your mouse above each step to know which law was used)
$$\eqalign{\require{action}\log_2(x^2-5x-28)=3 \ \ &\Rightarrow \ \ \mathtip{2^{\log_2(x^2-5x-28)}=2^3}{\displaystyle\rm because\, a=b \iff c^a=c^b. } \\ &\Rightarrow \ \  \mathtip{x^2-5x-28=8}{\rm \displaystyle\rm because\, b^{\displaystyle\log_bc}=c. } \\ &\Rightarrow \ \  \mathtip{x^2-5x-36=0}{\text{adding $-8$ to both sides}}.}$$
The last equation can be solved using the quadratic formula. And after you get your solutions, check them.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. So when I use the laws of logarithm I should look at it them as tools to solve equations not necessarily part of them?

Comment: @Utvecklaochförenkla What do you mean by  not necessarily part of them?

Comment: Well I have done about 10 in the past 20 minutes. I guess I mean that they are tools to solve equations where one is seeking the base of an exponent or the exponent itself. Am I correct?

Comment: @Utvecklaochförenkla The laws of logarithms can be considered as tools  to solve equations.

Comment: It would be -28-8 in your quadratic equation!

Comment: @Sid Thanks, fixed! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than distribute the log, exponentiate both sides:

$$2^{\left(\log_2(x^2 − 5x − 28)\right)} = 2^3$$

Comment: How did you see this? Was it because the 3 was isolated?

Comment: No. It's more that this way the $2$ and the $\log_2$ cancel. This is really the definition of the logarithm. Since there is just one isolated log term, this method eliminates the log and leave a quadratic.

Comment: As a side note, once you do find the solutions to the quadratic, don't forget to check that they work. Sometimes this approach leads to erroneous solutions.

Comment: @Utvecklaochförenkla : The way you see something like this is to recall that $\log_b a =c$ if and only if $b^c=a$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3):

How **exactly** you distribute the log?

$\log A + \log B= \log AB$ but

$\log(A+B) \ne \log A+\log B$

What you are looking at is a quadratic equation.

$x^2-5x-28=2^3$

Because, if $y=\log_2x$, then $2^y=x$

$x^2-5x-28-8=0$

$x^2-5x-36=0$

$(x-9)(x+4)=0$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\log_2\text{something} = 3 \text{ if and only if }2^3=\text{something}.
$$

That will get you the solution.